# Android SearchView: redirect to another search activity

Tags: android, android-searchmanager, android-search

I have a SearchView (support v7) with custom suggestions. Everything works fine.

But now I want to redirect to another search activity depending on the selected suggestion.

The custom suggestion table contains suggestions and search matches. And when ever the user clicks on a match I want to show the data without the search (because it is a match, no search is needed)

Currently I use the SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION in the search activity to open the other activity. It works but is this the best way to do this?

Ralph

Comment: That is exactly the point of the Intent, you used it in its most profound way.:)